# Oriented volume and determinants: Circularity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra

One often reads about oriented volumes as a motivation for determinants. In two dimensions you can scetch some nice pictures which may convince students that it is a good idea to have a closer look at alternating multi-linear functionals.

However, my feeling is that you are cheating because, if you come to the point where you really define orientations of vector spaces you *use* determinants.

Hence the question: Is there a definition of orientation which does not rely one determinants?

Comment: Are you really using determinants? Why not define an orientation as the choice of a connected component of the torsor of real frames?

Comment: @PaulReynolds : Could you explain what a frame is?  Or perhaps a real frame?  And then make your comments into an answer? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Do you literally just want any definition of orientation without using determinants, or do you want one that can be used to motivate determinants to students?  The former is considerably easier than the latter.

Comment: It suffices to distinguish between the two different orientations. An orientation is associated with a basis of the vector space, commonly known as a frame. So start with a frame and declare it to have positive orientation. Any other frame has positive orientation, if there exists a continuous path in the space of all frames joining the first frame to the other and negative orientation otherwise. In other words, orientation identifies the two connected components of $GL(n)$. The fact that there are two separate components and that orientation is well-defined is proved using the determinant.

Comment: But it's way easier just to define orientation directly using the determinant of the change-of-basis matrix and observing that it's well-defined.

Comment: Don't forget that a zero-dimensional vector space has only one frame but still has two orientations. (Sorry.)

Comment: I think I've seen some definition of a "frame" according to which that concept is more general that that of a basis. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @DeaneYang Your suggestion thus uses determinants (to show that $GL(n)$ has two path components) in the definitionof orientation.

Comment: Jochen, to quibble with this, in my definition of orientation the number of possible orientations is the number of connected components of $GL(n)$. Also, you can use the polar decomposition of invertible matrices to show that the number of components is 2. It's just that using the determinant is much easier.

Comment: @DeaneYang Okay, this a way to avoid the circularity. Thanks.